# Export all the subscriptions - FIWARE ORION Context Broker

Tags: subscription, fiware, fiware-orion

Is there any way to export all the subscriptions submitted on an instance of the FIWARE ORION Context Broker?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get subscriptions using `GET /v2/subscriptions` operation. However, note this is a paginated API, so if you have more than 20 subscription you will get only the 20 first ones. To get all them, page by page, you have to use `offset` and `limit` URI parameters. Check [NGSIv2 specification](http://telefonicaid.github.io/fiware-orion/api/v2/stable/) and also slides 48-50 in this [Orion introductory presentation](https://www.slideshare.net/fermingalan/orion-context-broker-20190214).

You can create a new subscription using `POST /v2/subscriptions` operation. You can use that operation to import subscriptions.

Answer (score 1):

You can all the subscription of an FIWARE Orion instance through the subscription list -> list subscriptions [NGSIv2 API](http://telefonicaid.github.io/fiware-orion/api/v2/stable/). Take care that probably you could need to specify the proper X-Auth-Token header key as well as the subscription could be associated to a specific Service and ServicePath that have to be defined as well in the Fiware-Service and Fiware-ServicePath header keys.

Comment: Ok, and if, then, I want to import them in a new Orion instance?

Comment: At the moment, the NGSIv2 specification does not allow the export/import functionality of subscription rules. You should create a script to create those subscriptions in the new Orion instance one by one, once that you obtain the complete list of them.